# Applications of algorithms to stock trading analysis

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, optimization, statistics

There is a new [Quantitative Finance SE site](https://quant.stackexchange.com/). However, I am interested in asking the "CS crowd":

> What are some interesting key references or surveys on applying algorithms to stock trading analysis?

There are many such references, however, I am particularly interested in those that would appeal to those with a CS background. Further, I am especially interested in those that find surprising applications of TCS or mathematics theory.